# AngularJS autocomplete tagging like StackOverflow's input tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, autocomplete, tags

I'm currently using [Angucomplete](https://github.com/darylrowland/angucomplete) for autocomplete and [ngTagsInput](https://github.com/mbenford/ngTagsInput) for tagging.

I'm looking for a solution that can do both: you can add tag if it's not from the autocomplete list.

Did someone run into something like that on Angular?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `ngTagsInput` it is possible to both select from autocomplete, or add tag if it's not in the list

Docs: http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/demos

See Demo: http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/bDx54d/